# Target child directory with php

Tags: php

I am running an argument based on urls to determine whether a user can access that area or not of the site. Is there a better way to instead of listing our every url just say anything after `/` cant be access. Here is my code it will better explain the problem:

```
if( $siteUrl == '/shop-portal/' && $userRole == 'customer'){
    header('Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/');
} elseif( $siteUrl == '/product-category/...' && $userRole == 'customer'){
    header('Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/');
}
```

so where I have `/product-category/` isa there a way instead of writing out `'/product-category/category1` etc etc every time can I just create one argument? Like anything after '/product-category/...' gets redirected?

Comment: You should share example of your site map.

Comment: What about one function that checks user role on each site and redirects user to some site if user does not have desired role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here if any one else needs to see it:

```
if(strpos($siteUrl, 'shop-portal') !== false && $userRole == 'customer'){
    header('Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/');
} elseif(strpos($siteUrl, 'product-category') !== false && $userRole == 'customer'){
    header('Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/');
}
```

I changed up the query to check if the string exists in the url!